# how to print the values stores in a calloc pointer (c)

Tags: c, pointers

Suppose I have a Pointer looks like:

```
char *tmp = calloc(1, 500);
```

Then I signed the value into the pointer:

```
char *token = "star";
for(int cur = 0, cur < 500,cur += 50){
       strncpy(&tmp[cur], token, 50);//each 50 units will get a value

}
```

Now I have a pointer with several values stored. What should I do print out the value one by one?

```
printf("--- %s\n", tmp); // this seems can only print the first one
```

I dont know how to jump or read to the next value, and keeping reading until the whole pointer is printed.

Comment: Why don't you try exactly like your `strncpy` argument? (Also, what is the point of `i`, and your `while` loop looks rather wonky like it's trying to be a `for`, but it will only execute once - you want `for (int cur = 0; cur < 500; cur += 50)`.) (And also use `strcpy` instead of `strncpy` as you copy from off the end of the `token` string, which is undefined behaviour.)

Comment: Why don't you use a `for` loop or declare `cur` *before* `while` ?

Comment: BTW compile with all warnings & debug info (`gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)...) and **use the debugger** `gdb`

Comment: At last, your `tmp` is probably declared with the wrong type. Consider using some `struct` with a [flexible array member](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flexible_array_member). You certainly should spend several days reading a good C programming book. If you insist on keeping such types, draw on a board a picture of your memory zone.

Comment: `for(int cur = 0, cur < 500,cur += 50){` --> `for(int cur = 0; cur < 500; cur += 50){`,   `printf("--- %s\n", &tmp[cur]); `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you copied null-terminated values into the array using (the corrected code):

```
for (int cur = 0; cur < 500; cur += 50)
    strncpy(&tmp[cur], token, 50);
```

You can print the values using:

```
for (int cur = 0; cur < 500; cur += 50)
    printf("--- %s\n", &tmp[cur]);
```

Answer (score 2):

> I dont know how to jump or read to the next value, and keeping reading
>   until the whole pointer is printed.

Well, you have made that more difficult on yourself than it needs to be. Why? *Jumping* or *reading* the next value in a block of memory is generally handled with *pointer arithmetic* or *array indexing* (which itself is just a convenient form of *pointer arithmetic*).

The *jump* or *offset* of sequential values stored in an array or block of memory is generally controlled by the *type* (e.g. `char`, `int`, `struct foo`, etc..). It need not be that way (as you can see in the other answers), but it is set up to work that way by default.

Each *type* has a size (in number of bytes), e.g. `sizeof (char) = 1`, `sizeof (int) = 4` (generally), `sizeof (char *) = sizeof (a pointer)` (which is generally `8` on x86_64 or `4` on x86. The *type size* controls the jump or offset to the next value, e.g.

```
size_t n = 10;
int *intarray = calloc (n, sizeof *intarray); /* allocates space for 10 ints */
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)                  /* fill array, 0, 10, 20, ... 90 */ 
    intarray[i] = i * 10;
```

By declaring `intarray` as type `int`, the compiler knows that `intarray + 1` is the address for the 2nd value (e.g. `10`) and `intarray + 2` is the value of the 3rd (`20`), and so on. **Note**, it is up to YOU to not exceed the memory bounds, e.g. `intarray + 9` is the 10th value (OK), `intarray + 10` is beyond the end of the block of memory allocated and invokes (*Undefined Behavior*).

*Pointer Arithmetic* provides another easy means of jumping from one value in memory to the next. Again, this works based on *type size*.

**NOTE:** you must always preserve a pointer to the beginning of the allocated block of memory so it can be freed later, so to jump to each of the values in `intarray`, either use *array indexing*, e.g., `intarray[i]`, or declare a second pointer to the beginning and use it for pointer arithmetic, e.g.

```
...
int *p = intarray;
size_t i = 0;

while (i < n) {                                 /* loop to do this 10 times */
    printf ("value[%zu] : %d\n", i, *p);        /* print the value stored at p */
    p++;                                        /* increment p to point to next */
}
```

**Also note:** all values must be initialized before you attempt to access them. (which since you used `calloc` you are safe - as all bytes were initialized to zero). However, when using `malloc`, the memory is uninitialized.

Array indexing and pointer arithmetic work for all types, even defined types like `struct foo { int a; int b; };`. Here, the compiler knows the size for `sizeof (struct foo)`, so you can use a pointer to `foo` just the same as you would use a pointer to `int` (or `char`, etc..)

Where you have made things hard on yourself is your are attempting to store a *string* (of size `0-49` chars) at intervals of `50` within `tmp`. While this is perfectly fine, the compiler cannot help you and you cannot use pointer arithmetic or array indexing (unless you roll-your-own) -- because **you made up the type** `char + 50`.

Now you can use a statically declared 2D array (e.g. `char tmp[10][50]`) to let the compiler help you. Then you can use indexing (e.g. `tmp[0], tmp[1], ...` or you can declare a pointer to array of 50 chars and you can use pointer arithmetic (e.g. `char (*p)[50] = tmp;` and then `p++` to get to the 2nd, etc..

(**note:** the parenthesis around `(*p)` are required due to C-Operator Precedence, without the parens you create an *array of pointers to char* (50 of them) instead of creating a *pointer to array*)

You can also dynamically allocate memory for any number of 50-char blocks. For example to do what you intended to do (in one big block), but telling the compiler that you want 50-char blocks (instead of one 500-char block that you have to invent indexing for), you can simply do:

```
char (*tmp)[50];                 /* 'pointer-to-array 50, type char' */
tmp = calloc (n, sizeof *tmp);   /* allocate storage for 10 tmp */
```

Now you can simply use either array indexing, or pointer arithmetic to fill and iterate over the words stored within each 50-char block in `tmp`.

To put the whole thing together, let's take two examples. The first will create an array of 10 blocks of memory (50-chars each) and using array indexing to fill and iterate over the contents of `tmp`, the second creates the same block of memory, but will use only pointers and a counter. (both examples do the exact same thing):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define NWRDS 10    /* number of words */
#define MAXC  50    /* max chars per-word */

int main (void) {

    size_t n = 0;                       /* number of words */
    char (*tmp)[MAXC];                  /* 'pointer-to-array 50, type char' */
    tmp = calloc (NWRDS, sizeof *tmp);  /* allocate storage for 10 tmp */

    if (tmp == NULL)                    /* validate all memory allocations */
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);

    strcpy (tmp[n], "my dog has fleas.");  /* copy stuff to first 3 blocks */
    n++;
    strcpy (tmp[n], "my cat has none.");
    n++;
    strcpy (tmp[n], "... lucky cat...");
    n++;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++)
        printf ("tmp[%zu] : %s\n", i, tmp[i]);

    free (tmp);                 /* dont' forget to free what you allocate */

    return 0;
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/ptr2array
tmp[0] : my dog has fleas.
tmp[1] : my cat has none.
tmp[2] : ... lucky cat...
```

**Memory Use/Error Check**

In any code you write that dynamically allocates memory, you have 2 *responsibilities* regarding any block of memory allocated: (1) *always preserve a pointer to the starting address* for the block of memory so, (2) it can be *freed* when it is no longer needed.

It is imperative that you use a memory error checking program to insure you do not attempt to write beyond/outside the bounds of your allocated block of memory, attempt to read or base a conditional jump on an uninitialized value, and finally, to confirm that you free all the memory you have allocated.

For Linux `valgrind` is the normal choice. There are similar memory checkers for every platform. They are all simple to use, just run your program through it.

```
$ valgrind ./bin/ptr2array
==6010== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==6010== Copyright (C) 2002-2015, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==6010== Using Valgrind-3.11.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==6010== Command: ./bin/ptr2array
==6010==
tmp[0] : my dog has fleas.
tmp[1] : my cat has none.
tmp[2] : ... lucky cat...
==6010==
==6010== HEAP SUMMARY:
==6010==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==6010==   total heap usage: 1 allocs, 1 frees, 500 bytes allocated
==6010==
==6010== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==6010==
==6010== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==6010== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

**Note:** exactly `500` bytes were allocated, just as you intended.

Always confirm that you have freed all memory you have allocated and that there are no memory errors.

Now, let's do the same thing again, using only pointers and a counter,

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define NWRDS 10    /* number of words */
#define MAXC  50    /* max chars per-word */

int main (void) {

    size_t n = 0;                       /* simple counter */
    char (*tmp)[MAXC], (*p)[MAXC],      /* 'pointer-to-array 50, type char' */
        (*p2)[MAXC];                   /* (3 of them) */
    tmp = calloc (NWRDS, sizeof *tmp);  /* allocate storage for 10 tmp */

    if (tmp == NULL)                    /* validate all memory allocations */
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);

    p = p2 = tmp;                       /* set all pointers equal to tmp */

    strcpy (*p++, "my dog has fleas."); /* copy stuff to first 3 blocks */
    strcpy (*p++, "my cat has none.");
    strcpy (*p++, "... lucky cat...");

    while (p2 < p)
        printf ("tmp[%zu] : %s\n", n++, *p2++);

    free (tmp);                 /* dont' forget to free what you allocate */

    return 0;
}
```

(output and memory check are the same)

While your question was basic, it is deceptively basic, because it implicates the fundamental concepts of indexing, pointer arithmetic and how both are tied directly to the *type* of values being handled. Also note, you can also declare `tmp` as `char **tmp;` and first allocate `10` pointers (e.g. `tmp = calloc (10, sizeof *tmp);)` and then allocate, copy each string as you go, (e.g. `tmp[n++] = strdup ("my dog has fleas.");` You are then resposible for freeing each individual word and then the pointers when you are done (that example is left for another day)

Hopefully this helps. Let me know if you have any further questions.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> for(int cur = 0, cur < 500,cur += 50){
> ```

This is wrong. The commas `,` should probably be semicolons `;` and you are unwittingly and incorrectly using the [comma operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator)

> Now I have a pointer with several values stored

Please define appropriate types. I don't see several "values" stored in your pointer.

However, you could see that pointer as (pointing to) an array of 500 `char`-s. Then `%s` is wrong in your `printf` (you might use `%c`).

Recommendations:

- spend several days reading some good C programming book. I'm even tempted to suggest taking a few weeks to read [SICP](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/) (an excellent introduction to programming, which does not use C) and practice, before learning C (which is a difficult programming language).
- specify (on paper, in English or in your native language), what your code is supposed to do, as precisely as possible.
- read carefully and several times some reference for *every* function that you are using notably [calloc](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/calloc), [strncpy](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strncpy), [printf](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf)
- read more about [pointers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointer_(computer_programming)) and pointer [arithmetic](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_arithmetic) and [C dynamic memory allocation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_dynamic_memory_allocation).
- compile with all warnings and debug info, e.g. `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)
- throw your code away, rewrite it entirely (till you get no warnings at all), use [rubber duck debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging); read about how to [debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)
- draw on a board the picture of your memory (with arrows for pointers, and boxes for locations)
- use a debugger e.g. `gdb` to run your code step by step and query the program's state, thus understanding precisely what is happening in your process.
- study -for inspiration- the source code of some *existing* [free software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software) (e.g. on [github](http://github.com/))

> What should I do print out the value one by one?

You first need to understand and define the [*types*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_system) involved. Perhaps you want arrays (of what type?) or `struct`-s (with what fields and types), maybe ending with some [flexible array member](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flexible_array_member)

> I dont know how to jump or read to the next value

You never explained (and probably did not understood) what "values" of what type do you have in mind. So jumping to the next one is meaningless (without expliciting values and types).

Perhaps you are confused about what strings are in C. Read a good book. Understand what is [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Maybe you want some array of

```
struct yourstruct {
   char name[50];
};
```

type. But then your code is wrong! E.g. it would start with

```
struct yourstruct *p = calloc(10, sizeof(struct yourstruct));
if (!p) { perror("calloc failed"); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); };
```

(when using dynamic memory allocation with `calloc` or `malloc` you should check against failure)

Comment: Only thing you missed was the link to [**How to debug small programs**](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) and advice to *"talk to the duck"*... Really, it helps `:)`

Comment: I just mentionned the duck

Comment: I already vote, I tried again and it tried to take it back `:)`